# How to create a ".gram" file for voice recognition application using CMUSphinx?

Tags: speech-recognition, grammar, cmusphinx

I am doing a project for searching a word in a text file using voice. So I need to write a grammar file for few words (min 10).

Can anyone tell me how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammar file are simple text files which you can create in a text editor, they just describe possible recognition variants, for example open a text editor and type the following:

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar hello;
public <greet> = (good morning | hello) ( nitin | rohit | ajit );
```

Then save it as a file with `.gram` extension and use in cmusphinx. This is a grammar file in JSGF format. You can learn more about JSGF syntax from documentation:

http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/

Comment: How to make a grammar file to accept all the dictionary words?

Comment: @NIket for all words you should create Language model with software. Like Srilm. I created from this link. It may help someone. https://hoxuanvinh.wordpress.com/2016/04/22/install-srilm-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @adnan ali: please send download link for windows (Srilm ). http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/download.html this link are not working.